# How to put Numbers on Google Map API markers?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i'm using GoogleMap API in my project where the position of a particular vehicle is rendered by using data in the DB, i have already implemented this, MY question is if its possible to get numbers on the Markers,e.x Vehicle A has been in 100 places from 1 to 2 of Decembre, i would like having numbers starting from 1 to 100 kinda showing its path,This is the create marker function of my Google API:

```
    function createMarker(point, IMEI, Velocity, Ora, Data) {   
      var marker = new GMarker(point, iconBlue); 
      var html = "<b>" + "Ora: " + "</b>" + Ora + "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Data: " + "</b>"+ Data + "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Velocità: " + "</b>" + Velocity + " km/h" ; 
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); });
      return marker;
     }
```

This is the code used whose output is used by the googmapsapi.html, the output is a simple xml file with a number of number of "markers" tags containig info such as long,lat,date and time, could this list be used somehow to get the numbers out?

```
         // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost","root","alphabravo");
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
                    }

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("tracciasat", $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
            }

// Select all the rows in the markers table
//$query = "SELECT * FROM sessione WHERE 1";
$query = "SELECT * FROM sessione WHERE Dat BETWEEN '$_GET[strt]' AND '$_GET[end]' AND IMEI = '$_GET[id]'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

    // Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
     echo '<marker ';
     echo 'IMEI="' . parseToXML($row['IMEI']) . '" ';
    echo 'Velocity="' . parseToXML($row['Velocity']) . '" ';
    echo 'Ora="' . parseToXML($row['Ora']) . '" ';
       echo 'Data="' . parseToXML($row['Dat']) . '" ';
    echo 'lat="' . $row['Latitudine'] . '" ';
         echo 'lng="' . $row['Longitudine'] . '" ';
               //echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
                 echo '/>';
                                                                }

          // End XML file
                        echo '</markers>';

          }
```

I would like to add the code regarding the Icon, which in my case is a blueIcon:

```
       var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following url to customize your markers icons :

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/examples-tutorials-custom-icons-for-markers?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys,following the link by @ChristopheCVB i accomplished it! Lemme share the code incase somebody needs in the future

This code basically creates 1000 icons with numbers ranging from 1 to 1000 written on them, a javascript file mapiconmaker.js is needed so either download it and put it together with other website files,

```
                 type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="mapiconmaker.js" language="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

  //<![CDATA[
    var customIcons = [1000];
    for(var j=0;j<1000;j++){
    var iconOptions = {};
  iconOptions.primaryColor = "#0000FF";
  iconOptions.strokeColor = "#000000";
iconOptions.label = j.toString().replace();
 iconOptions.labelColor = "#000000";
 iconOptions.addStar = false;
   iconOptions.starPrimaryColor = "#FFFF00";
 iconOptions.starStrokeColor = "#0000FF";
   customIcons[j]  = MapIconMaker.createLabeledMarkerIcon(iconOptions);
      }
```

Afterwards i use these markers when the googlemap api javascript function is rendering the map and when it is assigning the markers to each location that code is here:

```
            GDownloadUrl("second.php?strt="+ysdate+"/"+msdate+"/"+dsdate+"&end="+yedate+"/"+medate+"/"+dedate+"&id="+ide, function(data) {
                var xml = GXml.parse(data);
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var IMEI = markers[i].getAttribute("IMEI");
                var Velocity = markers[i].getAttribute("Velocity");
                var Ora = markers[i].getAttribute("Ora");
                var Data = markers[i].getAttribute("Data");
                var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var marker = createMarker(point, IMEI, Velocity, Ora, Data, i);

                map.addOverlay(marker);

              }
            });
          }
        }

        function createMarker(point, IMEI, Velocity, Ora, Data, i) {    
              var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[i]); 
              var html = "<b>" + "Ora: " + "</b>" + Ora + "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Data: " + "</b>"+ Data + "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Velocità: " + "</b>" + Velocity + " km/h" ; 
              GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); });
              return marker;
             }
```

I'm new to this site, but really love the spirit of getting free and fast help from experts, i will surely contribute as the time goes to atleast give back abit of what i get.Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the API doesn't support numbering the markers. I can think of two unsatisfying alternatives.

1. Set the zIndex, and then display the zIndex as the marker's title.
2. Use setIcon to change MarkerImage to a numbered graphic.

I usually have better answers than this one. I think I'm having an "off" day.

Comment: I just updated the code regarding the code of the icon, the issue is that the numbers are supposed to dynamic.So starting from the initial  result from the query it should start numbering them till the last one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make a custom marker because Goolge has the Google Chart Api: http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/chart. I use it to create numbered icons in my applications. It saves me a lot of headache.